pySimpleGui Popup Keep on top = True does not work on linux
I am creating an application that is running both on Windows and Linux.
I have a main Window and some settings popups, due to very specific targeted user it is absolutely mandatory for the popups not to disappear behind the main window.
Here is the popup creation code.
def createPopup(options,name):
layouts = {'Options':getConfigLayout,
'Printer settings':getPrinterLayout,
'Exit Options':getClosingLayout}
return sg.Window(name, layouts\[name\](options), keep_on_top = True, modal=True, finalize=True)

And the Main Window code:
popupWnd = sg.Window('Example' + getVersion(), createLayout(info, size=(1024,600)), margins=(0,0), background_color=getBorderColor(), no_titlebar=False, resizable=True, icon=getImgById('APP_ICON'), finalize=True)

On Windows the Popup always stays on top, so the code works, on Linux however the popup disappears behind the main window if you click on the main window.
P.S. Using Raspberry PI
Temporarily disabling the function of the window is not an option. Is there anything that can help?

Maybe you can check this https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/1399, not sure if it help.

On the Pi in particular, there are some combinations that don't work well together.  Modal, no titlebar, keep on top, full screen, hard coded sizes, etc, can have negative impacts on each other
